# How to write the SQL for the following problem?

Tags: sql, db2

I have to find, if there is any row in the table for which value of col2 is duplicate. Like in the specified scenario row 1 and 2 are duplicate as value of col2 is same.

```
Table
-------------------
Col1   Col2  Col3
1       1     4
2       1     3
3       2     2
4       3     1
```

At present what i am doing is

```
select count(*) from table group by col2 order by 1 desc
```

if the value of first row is > 1 then there are duplicates.

Please specify any optimized query for this problem.

**Note**  The table contains trillions of data, and there is no index on col2 [ if that matters to you ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * from MyTable where col2 in
(
select col2
from MyTable
group by col2
having count(*) > 1
) x
```

Comment: I was just close to post the same answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the following would give the right results in ms sql server... maybe in DB2 also

```
select * from t where col2 in (select col2 from t group by col2 having count(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Dave K is absolutely right.
You could also do it this way.
I suspect most optimisers will do exactly the same for both queries.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    MyTable t1
        (   SELECT   col2
            FROM     MyTable
            GROUP BY col2
            HAVING   count(*) > 1
        ) t2
WHERE   t1.col2 = t2.col2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to output the results of the duplicate records, you can try the following.

```
select * from
(
   select *
   ,row_number() over (partition by col2, order by col1, col2) r
   from MyTable
)dt
where r = 2
```